csh script doesn't resolve argv correctly
I have a text file with the following keywords:
bvca_sc=2.3
bvca=$bvca
bvca_sc=$bvca_sc

I need all of the above to be equal to 24.1
bvca=24.1
bvca_sc=24.1

doing this on command line works perfectly:
sed -i 's/bvca=2.3/bvca=24.1/g' file.txt
the same goes for these:
sed -i 's/bvca=\$bvca/bvca=24.1/g'
however, if I put this inside the script and pass the strings on the command line, it doesn't replace anything, it just keeps everything as it was.
#!/bin/tcsh -f

echo "\n*************************"
echo "***** Hack Netlist ******"
echo "*************************"

# Check if at least one argument (the filename) is provided
if ($#argv < 1) then
    echo "\n\e[1;41mUsage\e[0m: hack_netl <-i> <filename> <arguments>\n"
    exit 1
endif

# Check if the user wants in-place editing (-i option)
set inplace_editing = 0
if ("$argv[1]" == "-i") then
    set inplace_editing = 1
    shift
endif

# Get the filename (first argument)
set filename = $argv[1]

# Shift the arguments to remove the filename
shift

# Iterate through the remaining arguments in pairs
while ($#argv >= 2)

    # Get the first argument in the pair
    set arg1 = "$argv[1]"
    # Get the second argument in the pair
    set arg2 = "$argv[2]"

    # Display the replacement without writing to the file
    # echo "Replacing \"$arg1\" with \"$arg2\":"

    sed 's/$arg1/$arg2/g' $filename

    # Perform in-place editing if requested
    if ($inplace_editing) then
        sed -i 's/$arg1/$arg2/g' $filename
    endif

    # Shift the arguments to process the next pair
    shift
    shift
end

Then I am calling the function this way:
hack_netl file.txt "bvca=2.3" "bvca=24.2" "bvca_sc=2.3" "bvca_sc=24.2" "bvca=\$bvca_sc" "bvca=24.2" "bvca_sc=$bvca_sc" "bvca_sc=24.1"
What am I doing wrong?

sed 's/$arg1/$arg2/g' $filename Will pass the literal string s/$arg1/$arg2/g to sed.  None of the variables will be interpolated.  To get the values of the variables to sed, use double-quotes.  eg sed "s/$arg1/$arg2/g"
